# Search form within the Results page - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, search, react-router-dom

I am trying to build a simple search app with this flow:

1 - The Search Page has a SearchBar and a list with all the elements below it.

2 - When searching for a word(filtered by Query) within the Search Page this should redirect you to the Results Page.

3 - The Results Page has a SearchBar if you want to look for a different word and the results listed below.

Error: When searching for a different word (eg.AB instead of AA) I get an error *Cannot read property 'results' of undefined* and I don't know how to fix it. https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-cloud-k0poc?file=/src/data.js:96-101

I based the app on the following examples:

1  - [ReactJS - Pass props with Redirect component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064303/reactjs-pass-props-with-redirect-component)

2 - [Redirecting from a search form to a results page in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982036/redirecting-from-a-search-form-to-a-results-page-in-reactjs)

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` should fix your issue.

In your **SearchBar.js** add `event.preventDefault();` in submit method to stop the app from reloading.

```js
submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
  };
```

Comment: I completely forgot about that, thank you so much !!!!!!!